# Using CSS to hide <span> elements when they are empty

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this code:

```
<p class="alert-error">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</p>
```

I want to change the style of the CSS for "alert-error" when it shows `<span></span>`. The code is being generated by a system with limited backend customization. Sometimes the spans are filled with error messages.

The `:empty` selector doesn't seem to work cause I have to put it on the `alert-error` class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you need to style `.alert-error` when it contains only empty spans? That would require a parent selector which isn't available in CSS.

Comment: You're going to need JavaScript.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: What can you customize in your backend ? Is that an opensource backend ?

Comment: I agree, back-end customization would be a nice[r] solution. It may be easier than you think to have it give the `p` tag an extra class if it doesn't have error messages. Might be worth looking in to!

Comment: It's a Library Catalog system (Aleph) that is very clunky and doesn't allow to much customization. I have been able to do a lot with CSS and some of the HTML. But the messages that appear are hard to customize.

Comment: To be right about your question. You want to hide the empty `<span>` elements within the class `alert-error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm *guessing* based on what I can surmise from your markup structure that you want to hide the entire `.alert-error` element, not the `span` elements as stated in the question title. It doesn't really make sense to display `.alert-error` itself if its children are empty, since that would just result in an empty box.

The problem is that `:empty` itself does not match an element if it has child elements, even when all the children themselves are `:empty`.

[If CSS had a parent/has selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), you would theoretically be able to select `.alert-error` based on the fact that all its children are `:empty`. But since there doesn't exist such a selector in CSS yet, you will need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I made the css like this:

```
.alert-error span:empty {
    background: green;
}
```

and it works, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpVF6/)

Comment: OP wants to style the parent paragraph if the spans are empty, not the spans themselves. Plus, `:empty` deals with elements that have no children, not the content of an element.

Comment: And why does his title say **Using CSS to hide <span> elements when they are empty** ?

Comment: No, I read the whole question. But the title is part of the question, which sometimes isn't exactly clear...

Comment: @j08691 btw: `:empty` selector matches every element that has no children (including text nodes). (from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp))

Comment: @RaphaelMüller I want the "alert-error" class to display:none. So the whole red area would not show. I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: I was looking for :empty, so this did help me. OP could perhaps restyle the spans instead of the parent div.